# Thymeleaf - Iterate Object list based on an object's property

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a product object list and I want to iterate it in HTML page based on some conditions. I want to iterate this only for the products, which product type is 'BAR'. I have done this as follows.

```
<th:block th:if="${#strings.isEmpty(foo.destination)}" >
    <div  th:each ="product, prodStat:${foo.productList}" th:if="${product.type eq 'BAR'}" th:with="bar=${product}">                                   
        <div th:text="${bar.cityName}">London</div>                              
    </div>
</th:block>
```

But now I want product list to iterate only for the **first 5 'BAR' products only**. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first use the ["SpEl Collection Selection"](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-collection-selection) syntax to filter your `productList` to only elements matching the type "BAR". Then you can use the iteration status `prodStat` to only display the first 5 elements. Like so:

```
<th:block th:if="${#strings.isEmpty(foo.destination)}" >
    <div th:each="product, prodStat:${foo.productList.?[#this.type eq 'BAR']}" 
         th:if="${prodStat.index} lt 5" 
         th:with="bar=${product}">                                   
        <div th:text="${bar.cityName}">London</div>                              
    </div>
</th:block>
```

In the above you can see the iteration is now performed over `foo.productList.?[#this.type eq 'BAR']`, this is a filtered version of `productList` containing only the elements with the type (referenced using `#this.bar`) equalling 'BAR'.

The number of iterations is then limited using `th:if` and the iteration status `prodStat`.